# Finding string in file

Tags: python, file, if-statement

So I am trying to find a string from a file. My code looks like this:

```
fname=open('results', 'r')
lines=fname.readlines()
for i in lines:
      print i 
      s=lines[41]
      x= "0x80000680: 0x00000000\n"

      if (i == x) :
         stuff happens
```

My code reads the file just finds the line. that matches 'x' but it does not go into the if statement. A thing a noticed that when it prints out the line in the output it seems to have more spaces, but when looking at the variable it self it only has one. I have tried to put in the same amount of spaces for both results, but I am still not able to go into the if statement. Here is the output of 'i' when I print it when it gets to that line:
    `0x80000680:    0x00000000`
and it appears as :
`str: 0x80000680: 0x00000000\n`
when I look at the variables. If I look at x in the variables it shows `str: 0x80000680: 0x00000000\n`

Comment: Try `print repr(i)`. My best guess would be that the actual line in question is `"0x80000680:\t0x00000000\n"` or something similar.

Comment: Spaces are characters too. If it isn't going into the `if` that means it isn't the same line as `x`. You could consider using regex (though it may be overkill) to only match the parts of the line you want.

Comment: wouldnt it show special characters such as \t somce it shows \n? @smarx

Comment: @kirkpatt I have tried to match the spaces on both and it doesnt seem to work

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov I'm not sure I understand your question, but `print repr(i)` should show you exactly what to use on your line `x = ...`.

Comment: @kirkpatt thank for telling me about repr(i). I thought that since when I was looking at the variable i, I could see the \n at the end of the line I would be able to see \t as well. It turns out there there was a \t in the string.

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov Might want to direct that at smarx instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your line in your file **is not** `"0x80000680: 0x00000000\n"`

its easy to prove your line is not this

```
y="0x80000680: "+ "0x00000000\n" #ensure both x and y have different `id`
x= "0x80000680: 0x00000000\n"
print "ID:",id(x),id(y)
print y == x , y.strip() == x.strip()
```

as suggested you should `print(repr(i))` to actually see what your line really looks like

or you could try just checking if it startswith

```
i.startswith("0x80000680:")
```

or you could try using `re` to sort of match

```
re.match("0x80000680:.*0x00000000",i)
```